# Receiving incorrect HTTP response status codes

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to find broken links on a page.

I fetch all the available links on the page, then loop through them.  However, sometimes, the incorrect response code is received.

```
List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
System.out.println("Total no. of links are: "+ links.size());
java.util.Iterator<WebElement> it = links.iterator();

while(it.hasNext()){
    WebElement element = it.next();
    url = element.getAttribute("href");
    urlname=element.getText();

    if(url == null || url.isEmpty()){
        System.out.println(urlname +" - "+url+ ": URL is either not configured for anchor tag or it is empty");
        continue;
    }

    try {
        huc = (HttpURLConnection)(new URL(url).openConnection());                       
        huc.setRequestMethod("HEAD");                       
        huc.connect();                      
        respCode = huc.getResponseCode();

        if(respCode >= 400){
            System.out.println(urlname +" - "+ url +": is a broken link");
        }
        else{
           // System.out.println(url+" is a valid link");
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to provide more information. What is an 'incorrect' response code? What is the problem and how can we reproduce it? What input are you using and what output are you getting.

Comment: Fetching the all links from a web page, then using         huc = (HttpURLConnection)(new URL(url).openConnection());                       
        huc.setRequestMethod("HEAD");                       
        huc.connect();                      
        respCode = huc.getResponseCode();     this code getting http response. the problem is some time it giving me correct response status code and some times not.

Comment: Please explain what response codes you are getting and why they are 'incorrect'

Comment: For example for a link the above code is giving me code=500 and when i check it online the status code was 200.

Comment: It is quite possible that the anchor tag's href attribute has relative url instead of absolute, hence, it may not work properly if you directly try to open connection with the relative url.

Can you check -

Either all href values are absolute url's, or when you attempt to open connection you prefix the relative url with the base url ? (from the deleted answer by @Sachin Ramdhan Boob)